# c# app doesn't work on XP

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-xp, publish

i made a app that uses the `watIn library`, and target to .NET 3.5 (so it will work on XP to).
after i published the app on my PC, i installed it, and it worked well. but, when i tried it on different PC running XP, it didn't work. i made sure the PC I'm testing on is running .NET 3.5 or grater.

I'm running windows 7 and visual studio 2010.

the program work on Windows 7 (tried that on 2 PC's).
the program doesn't work on XP (tried that on 2 PC's).

On Xp i get this message:

```
Unable to install or run the application. The application requires that
assembly WindowsBase Version 3.0.0.0 be installed in the Global
Assembly Cache (GAC) first.

Please contact your administrator
```

my questions:

1. what should i do to make sure it work on XP?
2. if i start the development on .net 4, and then switch it to 3.5 and it still run, that mean i only used 3.5 code/features from the get go?
3. will visual studio give me compile Error if i run 4.0 code on app that i change his properties to target .net 3.5 in the middle of development?
4. is there a way to install the .net 3.5 framework with my app installer? (if it doesn't already got 1 on the PC)

(sorry for my English)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that the PC's running XP have .NET installed on them. Windows 7 will already come with the .NET Framework installed, but XP doesn't have the newer versions of the framework.

Also, if your project requires a specific version of the .NET framework, it's good to add it as a prerequisite in your setup installer.
[image: visual studio prerequisites]

Also, in your build, make sure you're targeting the proper framework.
[image: visual studio target framework]

links:
 - http://www.microsoft.com/net/download
 - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35976/Add-Prerequisites-of-NET-Framework-in-Visual-Studi

Comment: yeah i did that, in the first PC that uses XP i even installed the .net 3.5 framerwork to make sure it was the problem.

Comment: i follow the codeproject link and did it step by step twich but i dont see the dotnetfx folder. not in my project, not in the new setup project and not afther i publish the app aigan.